# audio tag in iphone js

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html

im trying to play a sound in a web app, it works in all nav, including in android but when i test it in an ipad or iphone the sound does not work, i've tried a lot of things but still get no solution, this is the last code that i've tried, as i said it works in all devices but i-things

```
 if($('#qty').text() !="")
                    {
                        //$("<audio id='chatAudio'><source src='ding.wav' type='audio/wav'>").appendTo('body');
                        $("<audio id='chatAudio2'><source src='ding.mp3' type='audio/mp3'>").appendTo('body');
                        // play sound
                    //  $('#chatAudio')[0].play();

                        $('#chatAudio2')[0].play();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Videos and audio on iOS require a touchevent to actually be enabled.
I'd recommend capturing an event after the page has loaded that will play then pause immediately, allowing you to play whenever you want afterwards.

Source: experience with this issue myself.

Comment: thank you, i've never heard about a touch event before i wiil read about it and i'll try to solve it.

Comment: i've tried but i dont think i'm doing it the right way, can you be more specific please?

Comment: In the way that I understand you're trying to achieve, I'd recommend having a listener for click or swipe on the body element, inside of that block have a check to see if the initial load process has been ran yet (just a bool will do). If it hasn't been ran already, get the audio element and do play then immediately pause. 

You should be able to control the audio element yourself after this